# Python regex match in groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to put the following string into two groups as follows:

```
groups(1) = "Hello1 Hello2 Hello3 Hello4"
groups(2) = "Bye1 Bye2 Bye3 Bye4"
```

I tried to do this using the following code. However, boths groups do not contain all the desired words.

```
import re


string = "Hello1 Hello2 Hello3 Hello4 Bye1 Bye2 Bye3 Bye4"
pattern = r'(Hello[0-9])+\w(Bye[0-9])+'
result = re.search(pattern, string)
groups = result.group
print("Group 1: {}\nGroup 2: {}".format(groups(1), groups(2)))
```

Comment: You aren't matching the white space between each word. Add `\s+?` after `[0-9]`

Comment: Don't use the phrase `groups()` it is a single group. Your question is leading up to `how can I get all specific words that are out of order, into a single array`. For example `"Hello1 Hello2 Bye1 Hello3 Bye2 Bye3 Bye4 Hello4 "`

Comment: A seeming answer is `(Hello[0-9]\s)+` but when you try it, the group will only contain Hello4. As each quantified pass clears the group old contents. A more meaningful approach is `(Hello[0-9](?:\sHello[0-9])*)`

Comment: However, the meaningful approach won't help if they are out-of-order as I mention, which requires a completely different approach.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If the grouping approach is not working, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @Puller - Usually, in your messages mailbox you only see comments that have your name in it (prepended with a @, and no spaces). Or comments to your own question or answers. Welcome to SO. I can't suggest anything because I do not know what you're trying to do. But, this works for your sample [Hello\[0-9\](?:\sHello\[0-9\])*)?.*?(Bye\[0-9\](?:\sBye\[0-9\])*)](https://regex101.com/r/ajy2Ss/1)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be doing the job, although being different from the approach used in my initial post.

```
import re


string = "Hello1 Hello2 Hello3 Hello4 Bye1 Bye2 Bye3 Bye4"
patterns = [r'Hello[0-9]', r'Bye[0-9]']
results = [re.findall(patterns[idx], string) for idx in range(len(patterns))]
print("Results:", results)
```

Comment: If you can use PyPi `regex` module you may use a single regex to get a similar result.